# comparing 2 dataframes with different shape

Tags: pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have some observed data for specific dates. Information of year, day, and month are in 3 different columns. and there are different measurements for moisture, temperature, and ... in other columns.
On the other side, I have daily model output for 5 consecutive years. I need to compare each measurement at a specific date with the model output for that specific date. Can you help me to do that? My observed data are more than 100 dates.

I tried lookup but did not worked

Comment: You can try to use `merge`(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lambda is correct, using the merge method would be your best bet. Based on your explanation of the problem, I have created sample dataframes with different shapes and merged them for comparing data:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample observed data
observed_data = {
    'Year': [2021, 2022, 2023],
    'Month': [1, 3, 5],
    'Day': [15, 22, 8],
    'Observed_Moisture': [0.4, 0.45, 0.38],
    'Observed_Temperature': [25.1, 26.5, 24.8]
}

observed_df = pd.DataFrame(observed_data)

# Sample model data 
model_data = {
    'Year': [2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023],
    'Month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Day': [15, 16, 22, 23, 8, 9],
    'Model_Moisture': [0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.39, 0.4],
    'Model_Temperature': [25.0, 25.1, 26.2, 26.3, 24.9, 25.0]
}

model_df = pd.DataFrame(model_data)

# Merge the dataframes on 'Year', 'Month', and 'Day' columns
merged_df = observed_df.merge(model_df, on=['Year', 'Month', 'Day'], how='inner')

# Calculate differences for moisture and temperature
merged_df['Moisture_Difference'] = merged_df['Observed_Moisture'] - merged_df['Model_Moisture']
merged_df['Temperature_Difference'] = merged_df['Observed_Temperature'] - merged_df['Model_Temperature']

# Display the resulting dataframe
print(merged_df)
```

In this code I am using `merge` method to combine the dataframes based on the `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` columns, ensuring an 'inner' merge to match only the rows with matching dates (thus, difference in shape of the two dataframes does not matter). Finally, I am calculating the differences for moisture and temperature.

Comparision results:

```
   Year  Month  Day  Observed_Moisture  Observed_Temperature  Model_Moisture  Model_Temperature  Moisture_Difference  Temperature_Difference
0  2021      1   15               0.40                  25.1            0.42               25.0                -0.02                     0.1
1  2022      3   22               0.45                  26.5            0.44               26.2                 0.01                     0.3
2  2023      5    8               0.38                  24.8            0.39               24.9                -0.01                    -0.1
```

You could have also used an iteration-based approach (where you iterate over each row and do things based on some conditions) but the `merge` method approach is more concise and efficient, especially for larger datasets.